# How To Convert record saved as Timestamp without timezone to normal date using php

Tags: php, function, postgresql, oop

I have a postgres database table that has a column of data type timestamp without timezone.... All the records in this column are saved as, for example, 2014-05-16 13:53:11 .... When I try to retrieve this information using a function it brings back a blank $variable or return. Is there a way in php I can be able to get this information? Even if it comes back as it is, date and time its ok. I would just like to be able to retrieve the information. Is there a specific php function I am supposed to use in order to retrieve the correct format of the data?

I didnt place the function here as I believe it useless, I am a beginner please help

Your prompt response would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres stores a timestamp as 8-byte integer (per default i.e. a date with time between 4713 BC and 294276 AD, using a microsecond precision) so the output is probably not a timestamp like you expected.

Have a look at [Date Type Formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) and try to convert your output to a string. Maybe thats what you need.

However, a possible more detailed description of your problem (schema, code, example,...) would be appreciated.

Comment: A timestamp in PostgreSQL is a date with time between 4713 BC and 294276 AD, using a microsecond precision. It has nothing to do with epoch.

Comment: Thanks Robert... I converted the output to a string and I managed to retrieve the data :-) Thanks guys much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you could use the DateTime-class to process an ISO-datetime and do whatever you need to do. Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Thanks Robert... I converted the output to a string and I managed to retrieve the data :-) Thanks guys much appreciated...